# How to change dates when filtering a queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to display a list of all payments done by the company. But I want to be able to filter the dates, only showing payments for example:

- In the last 30 days
- In the last 90 days
- Between two specific dates

Now, I know I can filter in my views between two dates, or before today for example.
But how I can I do this using something like a dropdown or a Data chooser on the template?

[image: someting like this]

Something like this for reference.

For reference, the payments model would be this:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.00)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use django forms with choice field and based on the value filter your queryset. e.g:

Choices:

```py
PERIOD_LAST_THREE_MONTHS = "last-three-months"
PERIOD_LAST_SIX_MONTHS = "last-six-months" # ..

PERIOD_CHOICES = (
    (PERIOD_LAST_THREE_MONTHS, _("Last 3 Months")),
    (PERIOD_LAST_SIX_MONTHS, _("Last 6 Months")), ..
)
```

**NOTE:** variables separated with hyphens because they will be used in query string of http request.

Utils:

```py
def get_period_date(period):
    if period == PERIOD_LAST_THREE_MONTHS:
        return timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=90)
    elif period == PERIOD_LAST_SIX_MONTHS:
        return timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=180)
```

This function will return a datetime object to filter your queryset with.

Forms:

```py
class DateForm(forms.Form):
    period = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PERIOD_CHOICES, required=False)
```

View:

```py
class PaymentFormView(base.TempleView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['payments'] = Payment.objects.filter(date__gte=get_period_date(self.request.GET('period'))
        return context
```

So basically based on the form value we get a date time object and filtered the queryset(Remember you have a `date` object). I have used template view instead of form view because I assume you do not want to accept post request. But again you can use form view and not allow post methods, this is up to you(It can be also done with function based views). Also consider the possibility that form can be empty so query string in http request may not have the `period` argument that may cause error and handle this situations how every you like.